# Не розмовний відповідник до словосполучення "впадати в дитинство"

Tags: відповідник

Мова - ДНК нації

[image]

Також на [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8/) вираз "впадати в дитинство" замінити на "дитиніти".

В СУМ-20 слово ["дитиніти"](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=22381&page=765) з позначкою розмовне. Який не розмовний відповідник до словосполучення "впадати в дитинство"?

Comment: Чи не є сам вираз "впадати в дитинство" (чи будь-який його відповідник) розмовним? Це - не діагноз, не хвороба... Це - чиєсь судження, яке хтось може виказати в розмові. Дуже "розмовна річ", як на мене.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На тому ж самому сайті [Мова ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/frazeologizmu/vpadat-v-detstvo) даються варіанти:

> здитинюватися, здитинитися; на дитячий розум зійти (перейти);
>   змалитися до дитини, (іноді) вистаріти розум.

Такі ж варіанти перекладу можна знайти і в [Російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Vyrhan_IO/Ros-ukr_slovnyk_stalykh_vyraziv.pdf).

Крім того, слово "дитинитися" (те саме, що й "дитиніти") може мати значення: "Поводитися як дитина; пустувати".

В цьому випадку нам допоможе [Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8), який пропонує такі варіанти:

> **ПУСТУВА́ТИ** (перев. про дітей - розважаючись, бавитися, гратися)**, БА́ЛУВАТИСЯ, ЗАБАВЛЯ́ТИСЯ, БЕШКЕТУВА́ТИ, ЖИРУВА́ТИ** + ще розмовні та діалектні варіанти -
>   **ДИТИ́НИТИСЯ, ДИТИНІ́ТИ, КАЗИ́ТИСЯ, ДУРІТИ, ШАЛІ́ТИ, ГАРЮВА́ТИ, ТЛУМИ́ТИСЯ,
>   ЗБИТКУВА́ТИ, ГАЙДАБУ́РИТИ, ВЕСЕЛИТИСЯ, ГРАТИСЯ.**

Також, гадаю, що можна використати також той же вислів із СУМу "поводитися як дитина".